# How to set additional Java Logger FileHandler within Ant JUnit Task?

Tags: java, ant, junit

i have a little weird task. The following (stripped) code is given (but i cannot change / enhance it):

```
public class CustomTestClass {

    /**
     * Logger.
     */
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.custom.testing");

    @Test
    public void simpleTestCaseOne(){
        logger.warning("simpleTestCaseOne: Not yet implemented!");
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTestCaseTwo(){
        logger.warning("simpleTestCaseTwo: Not yet implemented!");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Right now i use the following Ant-Code to run the tests:

```
<target name="Junit_Test" 
        depends="compile.test" description="Custom TestCase Runner">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes">
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=res/logging.properties" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="tests.class.path" />
                <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
            <test name="com.custom.testing.CustomTestClass" 
                haltonfailure="no" 
                todir="${reports.tests}/xml"
                methods="simpleTestCaseOne" >
                   <formatter type="xml" />
            </test>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

The logging.properties file just defines a *ConsoleHandler*, *FileHandler* and an output file for the logger of the TestClass.

When i run the ant script, it actually works fine, but i need to rerun the tests a few times and change the output file for the *FileHandler* each time.

Is it possible to add/change a FileHandler for the specified Logger **without changing code** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't particularly like this, but...

You could make a logging configuration file with a replaceable token in the value of the property java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern, e.g.

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/logs/@LOGFILE@.log
```

Then you could use the Ant [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with a [filterset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) to substitute the token, e.g.

```
<copy file="res/logging_tmp.properties" toFile="res/logging.properties" force="true">
  <filterset>
    <filter token="LOGFILE" value="your_value"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

You would do the copy before each execution of your unit tests, specifying a different value each time.

Comment: Hoi Chummer, yeah i understand why you don't like this, but this would actually work within my system. I'll wait a little longer, to see if there's a direct way to solve this... Otherwise, u'll get the correct answer ;) -- Thanks!!